# Problems with Redux dispatch (unexpected scroll)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

have you had problems with the Redux dispatch in React?
I have a form and OnBlur action on each input, when leaving the input field the dispatch is triggered causing the screen to scroll to the top of the page unexpectedly.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: is it a page scroll or page reload that is happening?
add your code to the question. without that it would be difficult to check what is happening

Comment: Share your progress. Otherwise, it is not clear what's the problem.

Comment: The problem is occurring in this small line of code:
  ====>  *dispatch(response);*

Comment: `Actions.saveAtendimento(props.beneficiario.agendamento.nnumeagend, params)
                    .then(res => {
                        dispatch(res);
                        setNotificacao(true)
                        setVariant("success")
                        setMessage("Gravando prontuário")
                        dispatch(Actions.changePodeEncerrar(true))
                    })
            }`

Comment: I know it's been two years but i'm having the same issue, did you find a cause in the end?